# ReactJS - how to fetch multiple data with useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm fairly new to react, right now I have a function that is fetching some data in my `useEffect` hook, using a loading state to manage component rendering and then loading my state component with that data, everything is working fine.

But now I have to implement another function to fetch some other data.

How can this be implemented in the best way possible? Do I need to create another `useEffect` for another fetch function?

Here is my code:

```
export default function Home() {
  const [ageOptions, setAgeOptions] = useState([])
  const [age, setAge] = useState('')
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)

  // get age option from API
   useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true)
    const fetchAgeOptions = () => {
     // transform the data to load properly in my react-select component
      function transform(data) {
        const options = data.map(function (row) {
          return { value: row.id, label: row.description, startAge: row.startAge, endAge: row.endAge }
        })
        setAgeOptions(options)
        setLoading(false)
      }
      api.get('someurl.com').then(response =>
        Object.values(response.data.rows)).then(data => transform(data))
    }
    fetchAgeOptions()
  }, [])


  return loading ? <div>Loading...</div> :
    <>
      <label>Age level</label>
      <Select
        value={age}
        options={ageOptions}
        placeholder="All"
        onChange={val => {
          setAge(val)
        }}
      />
    </>
}
```

Comment: 1. You need to make all your data transformation on redux level (inside actions for example). 2. You can call as much as you want requests on single useEffect hook, but it depends, is a data need to be loaded once or every time when some state changed. 3. If you want to call requests one after another, you need to use async/await or use callback hell with promises.

Comment: I would recommend you to combine all your requests and transformations into one redux action, and then just call only one action inside component useEffect hook.

Comment: @demkovych  To Op doesn't appear to be using Redux.

Comment: If they are completely independent api calls which should run simultaneously, I would definitely use two seperate `useEffect`-calls, because they might depend on different values. If the second api call depends on a value returned in the first call, use a single `useEffect` and call the second api in the `.then()` of the first promise (or use async/await).

Comment: @demkovych the data is going to be loaded only once. I'm using redux and saga.js. You think in this case (both api calls is used to fetch data for a combo), do I really need to use redux/saga for this?

Comment: @DamienFlury they are independent. Both calls is used to fetch data for different combos. But if I implement another useEffect, what about the loading state? One loading state for each?

Comment: @fjurr yes, you would need two loading states (or use a default value for each data, like null). In React 17 we will probably get `Suspense` for data-fetching, which will solve that problem nicely. But for now, you need to do that yourself.

Comment: i tried to implement using two useEffects, but didnt work, i tried using async await in useEffect and using both fetch calls in one useEffect didnt work ,,aslo i tried two then request for one fetch request and one fetch request in another, it didnt work and **always only one data is being stored**, i dont know what do do.

Answer (score 2):

Use a promise all

```
   useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true)
    const fetchMethod1 = () =>{...}
    const fetchMethod2 = () =>{...}
    const fetchMethod3 = () =>{...}
    const fetchMethodN = () =>{...}
  Promise.all([fetchMethod1,fetchMethod2,fetchMethod3,fetchMethodN]).then(data=>{
// DATA IS AN ARRAY AND THEY ARE IN ORDER AS PLACED IN 
})
    
  }, [])
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to create a custom hook called useFetch having inside of it both useEffect and useState, it should return state (initial, loading, error and success) and result, then call the second effect only when the first has the correct state.

Answer (score 0):

Your current useEffect will only run on mount (because you added the empty brackets at the end of the use effect []). If you are planning on only calling this function one time (on mount) then you can put it in the same useEffect. If you want to call a function every time the state of something updates then all you have to do is make a separate useEffect with the state as a dependency.

```
useEffect(() => {

  }, ['variable-here-on-update-will-call-whatever-is-in-the-useEffect'])
```

Here is an example on mine:

```
//will run on componentDidMount
useEffect(() => {
  setError(false);
}, []);

//will run if error is updated in parent component
useEffect(() => {
  if (error && error.body) {
    setError(true);
  }
}, [error]);
```

I would also recommend taking out your 'fetchAgeOptions' function from the useEffect (and add it above) as you are calling to it anyways. This way it is not a private function to the useEffect and it will look cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Just like you can use the State Hook more than once, you can also use several effects. This lets us separate unrelated logic into different effects:

```
function FriendStatusWithCounter(props) {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  useEffect(() => {
    document.title = `You clicked ${count} times`;
  });

  const [isOnline, setIsOnline] = useState(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    function handleStatusChange(status) {
      setIsOnline(status.isOnline);
    }

    ChatAPI.subscribeToFriendStatus(props.friend.id, handleStatusChange);
    return () => {
      ChatAPI.unsubscribeFromFriendStatus(props.friend.id, handleStatusChange);
    };
  });
  // ...
}
```

Hooks let us split the code based on what it is doing rather than a lifecycle method name. React will apply every effect used by the component, in the order they were specified.

React Docs - Effect Hook https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html